# Azure timer function not updating log

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created a simple (out of the box) Azure function using a timer trigger. I expect to see the output in the log, but there is nothing there.  Monitor shows it is working.

Cron is set to */1 * * * * *  (every second)

I don't see a button to turn logging on/off.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure function apps logs not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657584/azure-function-apps-logs-not-showing)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to switch logging on, it should be on by default. I just created a function with your cron expression, and logs work just fine.

However, logs in the portal are not very reliable. Try reloading the page or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44657743/1171619) to a similar question.