# Configuring Log Level for Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Function App which has Application Insights configured. My functions have some `LogTrace()` messages in but they are not being captured by AppInsights. Do I have to configure a minimum loglevel somewhere?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Please take a look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#log-configuration-in-hostjson) on how to set log level for function v1 or v2.

In the file `host.json`, for the filed "Function", set its value to Trace. Then LogTrace() can be logged into application insights.

Sample `host.json` for Azure function v2, which can log trace messages to Application Insights:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

And if you publish your function app with visual studio, you can modify your host.json file as per the above before publishing.

And if you want to change the log level in azure portal, please follow this:

In Azure portal, navigate to your function app -> in the function app settings, make sure enable the Read/Write, then change log level to trace in the `host.json`.

[image]

Comment: Useful answer, thank you.  May I ask, is it possible to control the log level for each function separately?  The URL below suggests it is possible to specify Function.MyFunction - but I am unsure what MyFunction refers to here.  Is this the name used in the "FunctionName" attribute in C# for example?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Comment: @cbailiss, could you please post a new issue for this?

Answer (score 34):

I can't see any host.json file in azure portal but I could update it from application settings(environment variable). To replace default log level set key `AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__LogLevel__Default` and value `Trace`/`Debug`/`Information` or whatever you want. Like for me in my host.json `Default` is `Trace` but in azure it is `Information`. So just add new environment variable(Application settings) and prefix with `AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__LogLevel__` for all the keys of loglevel and set the desired value and your host settings will be overridden.

You can read more [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values)

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been going back and forth for days trying to figure out why i couldn't get my debug logs to show locally. This fixed it! And thank you for the link!

Answer (score 29):

To further add to @Ivan Yang's excellent answer, you can specify a minimum logging level *per function* in v2 of Azure Functions. (I have not verified if it does/doesn't work in v1) Using his example `host.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Function.FunctionA": "Warning",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

`Function.FunctionA` is assuming you have a function named (via the `FunctionName` attribute) "FunctionA", e.g.:

```
[FunctionName("FunctionA")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "")]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
  ...function code here
}
```

So whatever value you specify in the `FunctionName` attribute can be used to explicitly define a minimum log level just for that function. In the `host.json` example above, all functions, by default, will have a minimum log level of `Trace` while FunctionA will have a minimum log level of `Warning`.

Comment: Modifying a file to change log levels is not ideal - is there a way to do it via ENV variables or application configuration?

Comment: @Karpik, I don't believe so. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658607/overriding-log-level-for-azure-functions.

Comment: I've actually found it and it works!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405020/configure-loglevel-of-azure-function-using-environment-variables