# How to configure ApplicationInsightsTelemetry, in .NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

I am trying to adapt Application Insights to my liking. And I have some problems. I have it mounted like this.
In the startup.cs class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

In the Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.AddApplicationInsights("73985d32-dc3b-4a7e-915e-aa7ef37fbef8");
                    logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Information);
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

So I avoid using the appsettings.json configuration, because the log level will be variable.
My first question is, how can I make the dynamic log level, by querying the database?
Another question, is how can I add a custom parameter, type customer_name?

Finally, how can I make Application Insights register the values ​​that I want, using:
Only record the values ​​that come out of these functions, for example, if there is an exception, you would not have to register it.

```
_logger.LogInformation("Test info");
_logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
```

Comment: If you want to make dynamic logging to AI, you have to implement an `ITelemetryProcessor`. Then your logger has to *always* push the messages to AI and your processor makes the filtering (by omitting the call to `_next.Process(item);`).

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

**About your first question**

I think it's impossible,for more details, you can check bowman's answer.

[Overriding Log Level for Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658607/overriding-log-level-for-azure-functions)

**About second question**

Jitendra Patil's code really great, this should be what you need.

[Adding custom properties for each request in Application Insights metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036729/adding-custom-properties-for-each-request-in-application-insights-metrics)

[image]

[image]