# What is the default logLevel threshold in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

It's clear how to *override* log levels in `host.json`:

- [Configure the trace level for logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#configure-the-trace-level-for-logging)
- [Configuring Log Level for Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408032/configuring-log-level-for-azure-functions)

What is the default value though if it's not set explicitly?

A link to documentation would be appreciated for easier future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `default LogLevel` is `Information`.

Actually, `azure function` follows the `ASP.NET Core` log level configuration. And in ASP.NET Core, if you don't explicitly set the minimum level, the default value is `Information`.

Reference docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&preserve-view=true#default-minimum-level).